# Scoped enumerations: error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘Handle’ in initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer

I am reading the `Scoped enumerations` page from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

[image]
So I decided to give it a try:

```
$ cat e.cxx 
#include <cstdint>
enum class Handle : uint32_t { Invalid = 0 };
int main()
{
  Handle h { 42 }; // OK
  return 0;
}
$ g++ -std=c++11 e.cxx
e.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
e.cxx:5:17: error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘Handle’ in initialization
   Handle h { 42 }; // OK

             ^
```

Using:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 5.3.1-14) 5.3.1 20160409
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If I now check the C++11 support in GCC, it appears as if everything is supported since [GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11).

So which page am I reading it wrong ? The example for `Score enumertions` is not 100% correct, or the support for C++11 in GCC is still incomplete ?

Comment: You try to use a c++17 feature with c++11, it's totally normal that doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enum class` (or `enum struct`) creates a *strong* type. It can not naively be initialized using the underlying integer type, it needs to be explicitly casted, at least in C++11 and C++14.

The reference screenshot you show is from the upcoming C++17 standard, which relaxes the the requirements a little, and allows that type of initialization.

Comment: That would imply a typo on `cppreference` that got unnoticed so far...right ?

Comment: @malat take a look at example code in cppreference: it's noted as "since c++17", so it's not surprising that is not compliant with c++11

Comment: I've just tested it with g++ 6.1.1 and it failed too (-std=c++17 should be enabled by default) and with explicitly added -std=c++17 it is not working either.

Comment: @KIIV I haven't tested with GCC, but works with a recent checkout of Clang (using `clang++ -std=c++1z`).

Comment: @KIIV what makes you think C++17 is enabled by default in GCC6? Release notes say `gnu++14` is the default. C++17 cannot be the default since there is no such a thing yet. (Even the feature set going into c++17 is not defined yet)

Answer (score 1):

The wording in question comes from [P0138R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0138r2.pdf): Construction Rules for enum class Values. As you can see, the paper is dated March 2016 - quite a few years too late for C++11!

The wording is included in the latest working draft [N4582](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf) in [dcl.init.list] as suggested:

> Otherwise, if T is an enumeration with a fixed underlying type (7.2), [...]

clang 3.9 apparently has already implemented this example, but I wouldn't be surprised that such new features aren't supported by compilers yet. Give it a while.